# Unterschied zwischen "erlangen" und "erringen"?

Tags: meaning, translation, difference, german-to-english, idiom

Kann jemand mir bitte erklären, ob beide Worte die gleiche Bedeutung haben?

> Einen Sieg erlangen oder erringen?
>   Die Freiheit erlangen oder erringen?

Comment: "Langen" => nach etwas greifen / "Ringen" => um etwas kämpfen...... "erlangen" => etwas bekommen, indem man danach greift (kann eifriges Bemühen suggerieren)   / "erringen" => etwas bekommen, nachdem man darum gekämpft hat

Comment: Aber unterm Strich bedeutet es nur, dass man etwas "erreicht" hat, etwas "gewonnen" hat, etwas "bekommen" hat, etwas "erhalten" hat. Also im Wesentlichen  die gleiche Bedeutung mit nur einem leichten Unterschied in der Art und Weise, wie man das Ziel erreicht hat. Beispielsweise ringt ein Ringer wortwörtlich um den Sieg, ein Langfinger erlangte aber lediglich die goldene Uhr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nein, diese beiden Wörter haben nicht dieselbe Bedeutung:

- **erlangen**
  Dieses Wort bedeutet ungefähr: etwas **erreichen.**

  > - Das Flugzeug **erlangt/erreicht** in wenigen Minuten eine Reiseflughöhe von 11.000 Metern.
  > - Der Apfelbaum in meinem Garten **erlangt/erreicht** nächstes Jahr ein Alter von 40 Jahren.
  > - Nach 3 Wochen im Koma **erlangte** Heinrich wieder das Bewusstsein.

  Das letzte Beispiel macht klar, dass sich *»erlangen«* nicht immer durch *»erreichen«* ersetzen lässt.
- **erringen**
  Das bedeutet: Etwas erkämpfen, also etwas als Folge eines gewonnen Kampfes erhalten.

  > - Nach drei Monaten zäher Verhandlungen und erst nach zwei Streiks **errang** die Gewerkschaft die Zusage zu Gehaltserhöhungen für die Belegschaft.
  > - Iris konnte durch hartes Training und größten Einsatz im Wettkampf einen Platz unter den ersten Drei **erringen.**
  > - Wem der große Wurf gelungen, eines Freundes Freund zu seyn; wer ein holdes Weib **errungen,** mische seinen Jubel ein!

  Das letzte Zitat stammt aus der »Ode an die Freude« von F. Schiller und verwendet das Wort in einer gehobenen aber auch veralteten Art und Weise. Die Sichtweise, dass man Frauen *erobern* oder *erringen* muss (was eine gewisse Gegenwehr der Frau impliziert), gilt heute als überholt.

Comment: Ihre Erläuterung ist einfach toll. Vielen vielmals Dank !

Comment: Gute Erklärung. Ich denke, bei Schiller könnte der Kampf auch zwischen Erringer und Konkurrenten statt Frau stattfinden.

Comment: @Cacambo: Auch diese Sichtweise ist überholt. Niemand kämpft heute mit einem anderen Mann in der Hoffnung, dass die von beiden begehrte Frau sich dann dem Sieger hingibt. Und wenn doch, bleibt diese Hoffnung häufig unerfüllt. Frauen ist in den meisten Fällen herzlich egal, wie solche Kämpfe ausgehen. Frauen wählen Männer nach ganz anderen Kriterien aus.

Comment: Ich stimme dir zu.